# Flutter: force LTR direction for widget in a RTL app based on intl

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-layout, arabic

I'm working with a boilerplate flutter app template with built-in redux support, and Hebrew RTL orientation using ***flutter_localizations*** and ***intl*** packages.

The whole app, and every new widget I create has a native RTL directionality, properly.

I have a text input field to get the user phone number. I would like this input field, with all of it's style and inside functionality to behave in a LTR manner. this is also true for other input fields I might have, like email (which is always in English)..

It seems that there is a conflict between the overall Directionality, determined by the app ***intl*** configuration, and a new Directionality widget I'm trying to "force" on my text fields to specifically swap their behavior:

```
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.LTR,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: phoneController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Running this code results in the following error:

```
lib/modules/login/login_page.dart:54:54: Error: The argument type 'TextDirection/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextDirection/*2*/'.
 - 'TextDirection/*1*/' is from 'package:intl/src/intl/text_direction.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.17.0-nullsafety.2/lib/src/intl/text_direction.dart').
 - 'TextDirection/*2*/' is from 'dart:ui'.
                        textDirection: TextDirection.LTR,
                                                     ^
```

What am I missing here? how can I accomplish the desired behavior?

Comment: `TextDirection` is defined in botn `dart:ui` and `intl` packages - you need that one from `dart:ui`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt notice these are 2 separate import options. using Directionality from package:flutter/material.dart and not the intl package did the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was me.
I was counting on the IDE auto-complete for imports, and it turns out both the ***intl*** package, and the regular ***flutter:material*** package expose `Directionality` options:

- using the ***intl*** option for `textDirection` tries to override the overall config, which **fails**:

```
child: Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.LTR,
```

- However, using the `package:flutter/material.dart` option **works** as expected:

```
child: Directionality(
   textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,   // notice lower case
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:ui' as UI;

UI.TextDirection direction = UI.TextDirection.ltr;

Directionality(
            textDirection: direction,
            child: widget());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply direction to all pages of your app, you can use builder in `MaterialApp` :

```
void main()  {
  runApp(DirectionApp());
}

class DirectionApp extends StatelessWidget  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can fix this by adding `as <your chosen import name>` to the end of eg. the statement that imports 'intl'. You would then have to prefix all your calls to methods in this library with `<your chosen import name>.`

Not ideal though.